# Upper limit of a sequence, an example

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

This is example 3.18 ( b ) from Rudin's principles. Consider the sequence $$s_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

In order to find the upper limit, that is the supremum of the set $E$ which consist of all subsequential limits of $s_n$, I consider subsequences such that $n$ is even. Certainly the limits of these subsequences are positive and form the largest subset of $E$. Therefore the supremum of this subset is the supremum of E. $$\lim_{n'\to\infty} s_{n'}=\lim_{n'\to\infty}\frac{1^{n'}}{1+\frac{1}{n'}}=1$$

where $n'$ denotes that these numbers are even. Therefore the upper limit of the sequence is $1$. Are my arguments sound? Letting $n\to\infty$ here is a problem, because $1^{\infty}$ is not determined.

Comment: Warning: $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n$ should not be thought of as $1^\infty$. Think of it this way: If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $1^n=1$, right? So the sequence $(1^n)_{n}$ is equal to the constant sequence $(1)$. The limit of this is of course $1$.

Comment: I am surprised that the minus does not have parenthesis

Comment: Yes indeed. I edited the text.

Comment: This statement is not correctly written for what you intended to say: "Certainly the limits of these subsequences are positive and form the largest subset of $E.$" Note that the largest subset of $E$ is $E,$ which contains some negative numbers, but NONE of "the limits of these subsequences" are negative numbers.